# angular: routes and security considerations with protected pages

Tags: angularjs, security, cookies, angular-routing

We want to have an **app behind a very simple access code verification step**. So if a user comes to the site, she has to provide an access code first. If the code is correct she will be shown the app, else an error message appears. The access code page is one route (ng-route), the app has another.

Now my question:

I thought the server would generate a cookie for the client when the access code is correct, and angular can then switch the route.
However, isn't it easy-peasy to just add the cookie for an attacker and then she gets access? Also, if I set a variable say "access_granted" in the $rootScope or elsewhere, a malicious attacker could just exchange the whole javascript (or edit it) and just add that variable manually, couldn't she?

In other words, how can I have this done secure in angular? Or should I refrain from using angular-route in this case and have only the server create the views when the access code is correct?

Comment: Sensitive or private data has to be secured in the backend, everybody can enter the javascript app, like you say.

Comment: I thought so...:) Thanks

Comment: Look into using a $http interceptor in angular. When a $http request to the backend returns a 'Not Authorized' response, you can use that to log the user out.